# how to convert string into query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to add string in which we have And clause. but when we apply that string which query this string will be treated as Query and fulfill all and conditions
I have a query like:-

```
Declare @WhereQuery varchar(max)

SET @WhereQuery='class=''BCA'' and RollNo=10 AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM StudentMaster WHERE MARKS > 50)'

SELECT  * into #TempTable1
from StudentMaster 
where @WhereQuery
```

I also don't want to use execute or exec function to run this query. 
I am going to add string with query mention as above but this will not work properly.
The variable which I have added after where clause is treated as string but I want this string is treated as Query. Please help. I also don't want to use execute or exec function to run this query.

Comment: -1 for choosing dynamic SQL but then saying "not EXEC".

Answer (score 3):

The below approach works fine. but be extra careful as it is susceptible to sql injection if user provides the input.

```
create table #TempTable1 (.....)

Declare @selectQuery varchar(max)
set @selectQuery = 'SELECT * into #TempTable1 from StudentMaster '

Declare @WhereQuery varchar(max)

SET @WhereQuery='where class=''BCA'' and RollNo=10 AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM StudentMaster WHERE MARKS > 50)'

exec (@selectQuery + @WhereQuery)
```

Comment: I don't want to use execute or exec function to run this query.

Comment: In that case, construct the query in Java/.Net and then prepare it and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You *have* to use EXEC or [sp_exeutesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) if you *want* to run dynamic SQL.

If you don't *want* to use EXEC then write non-dynamic queries:

```
SELECT  * into #TempTable1
from StudentMaster 
where class='BCA' and RollNo=10 AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM StudentMaster WHERE MARKS > 50)
```