# converting string into query in sql server

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert string into query in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884999/how-to-convert-string-into-query-in-sql-server)

How to add string in which we have And clause. but when we apply that string which query this string will be treated as Query and fulfill all and conditions

I have a query like:-

```
Declare @WhereQuery varchar(max)

SET @WhereQuery='class=''BCA'' and RollNo=10 AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM StudentMaster WHERE MARKS > 50)'

SELECT  * into #TempTable1
from StudentMaster 
where @WhereQuery
```

**I also don't want to use execute or exec function to run this query**

Answer (score 1):

You *have* to use EXEC or [sp_exeutesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) if you *want* to run dynamic SQL.

If you don't *want* to use EXEC then write non-dynamic queries:

```
SELECT  * into #TempTable1
from StudentMaster 
where class='BCA' and RollNo=10 AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM StudentMaster WHERE MARKS > 50)
```